# Access field in Mock

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a hard time to visualize this.

Here is the scenario.

My Unit Test

```
    public void AddStudentTest()
    {
        StudentService target = new StudentService (new Mock1(),new Mock2(), new Mock3(), new Mock4(), new Mock5());
        string name  = "Sample Name";
        int actual = 0;
        string[] userNames = new string[] {"Sample User Name" };
        string[] roleName = new string[] {"Sample Role" };
        target.AddStudent (name, userNames, roleNames);            
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    }
```

I am testing a method in Mock 3. Unfortunately, the method return type is VOID. I need to check if the transaction is successful or not. I added a field resultFlag on this method "AddStudent" but how can I access this from unit test?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you really testing Mock3 method, you have access to that code so I belive your test case maybe rewritten to something like

```
public void AddStudentTest()
{
    var dbMock = new Mock3()
    StudentService target = new StudentService (new Mock1(),new Mock2(), dbMock, new Mock4(), new Mock5());
    string name  = "Sample Name";
    int actual = 0;
    string[] userNames = new string[] {"Sample User Name" };
    string[] roleName = new string[] {"Sample Role" };
    target.AddStudent (name, userNames, roleNames);                    
    Assert.IsNotNull(dbMock.Students.FirstOrDefault())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this code yesterday and I'm getting incorrect result. on my mock3, after the successful "Add" I raised the resultflag to 1 from 0, unfortunately, AddStudent is on Class2 (sample) and calling the method in Mock Method which returns integer to class 2. What I need is that, get the flag value direct from the Mock class to Assert in test method.

Comment: @Scuttle, quite the opposite I see need of refactoring your code.